# Fliping each character from lower to upper and vice versa for all file and directory names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Example: given directory name "JaCa" rename it to "jAcA" and filename "asdfFDSA.TXT" to "ASDFfdsa.txt".

```
#!/bin/bash 

content=(`ls $1`)

for any in ${content[@]} ; do
    mv $any ${any~~}
done
```

I assume that the result is trying to mv a string into something, which is not how mv works.

How do I actually get file/directory names into $any instead of strings of names?

`ls zad8` gives `JaCa  LjKiOuLoPtLllllllllOOOOOOOO  a  asdfFDSA.TXT  wAcA`

`bash 8.sh zad8`

```
mv: cannot stat 'JaCa': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'LjKiOuLoPtLllllllllOOOOOOOO': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'a': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'asdfFDSA.TXT': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'wAcA': No such file or directory
```

Comment: @oguzismail ```for any in "$1"/*``` doesn't work and tries to execute the code upon the parameter dir

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script was trying to mv `$any` which exists in zad8 and not in the current dir.

Changing `$any` to `$1/$any` corrects this problem by specifying zad8 as the directory in which $any resides and `$1$/{any~~}` tells the script to place it in zad8.

```
#!/bin/bash 

content=(`ls $1`)

for any in ${content[@]} ; do
    mv $1/$any $1/${any~~} 
done
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.